# Using QTY in Rule-Based Product Relations

Tags: quantity, rules, product-relations, ee-1.14

Using Magento EE 1.14 and would like to be able to use the inventory quantity for rule-based product relations (related, upsell, cross sell). However, I don't see a way to make the quantity available as a criteria in the conditions dropdown.

Anyone have a solution for this?

We allow backorders on all of our products, so I would prefer that recommendations are made based on products that currently have a quantity of 1 or more in stock. Without this capability, I can't think of another way to limit rule-based relations to in-stock items only.

Comment: Alternatively, if I cannot filter based on the quantity > 0, is there a way to control the sorting of products matching the rule by the quantity in descending order?